# Do not use 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute'. Use the 'dynamic' keyword instead

Tags: c#, webmatrix

I copy and paste source of `WebMatrix.WebData.IDatabase` but VStudio mark **Dynamic** words and said

> Do not use 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute'. Use the
>   'dynamic' keyword instead.

**Why i get this error when original .net framework used it?**

The source code is here:

```
namespace WebMatrix.WebData
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    internal interface IDatabase : IDisposable
    {
        int Execute(string commandText, params object[] args);

        [return: Dynamic(new bool[] { false, true })]
        IEnumerable<object> Query(string commandText, params object[] parameters);

        [return: Dynamic]
        object QuerySingle(string commandText, params object[] args);

        [return: Dynamic]
        object QueryValue(string commandText, params object[] parameters);
    }
}
```

and I get same error here:

```
namespace WebMatrix.WebData
{
    internal class DatabaseWrapper : IDatabase, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Database _database;

        public DatabaseWrapper(Database database)
        {
            this._database = database;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this._database.Dispose();
        }

        public int Execute(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return this._database.Execute(commandText, parameters);
        }

        [return: Dynamic(new bool[] { false, true })]
        public IEnumerable<object> Query(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return this._database.Query(commandText, parameters);
        }

        [return: Dynamic]
        public object QuerySingle(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return this._database.QuerySingle(commandText, parameters);
        }

        [return: Dynamic]
        public object QueryValue(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return this._database.QueryValue(commandText, parameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you copying this source *from*, exactly? It looks to me like you're using an old source

Comment: @Marc Gravell I used .net reflector to decompile it...

Comment: ah, right; then that **isn't the source code**. Reflector often gets things "wrong", because it **isn't showing you source code**. Or alternatively, reflector gets things "right" by showing you what is really there. But : that can be different to what you would write as code.

Comment: @Marc Gravell i think you right.. i try to use your source code link ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That maps to:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> Query(string commandText, params object[] parameters);
dynamic QuerySingle(string commandText, params object[] args);
dynamic QueryValue(string commandText, params object[] parameters);
```

The only reason I can think of to use the alternative syntax is for compiling it on a down-level compiler that doesn't know about the `dynamic` keyword. However, `[DynamicAttribute]` has only existed since .NET 4.0, which includes a compiler with `dynamic` support. Thoughts:

- is it perhaps using the asp.net compiler, which might not necessarily be configured to use vLatest
- does this perhaps relate to early development against CTP builds, when `dynamic` was incomplete

If you look at the [current source](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WebMatrix.WebData/IDatabase.cs), it uses `dynamic`, supporting the hypothesis that any `[Dynamic]` usage was purely transitional.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/WebMatrix.WebData/IDatabase.cs is good source for using.. :D